# Rails - regex to find specific date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

In app I build to learn rails, I am working on finding data. Now I have this case: in this text, I want to find the right delivery date.

"delivery date 01/12/2015 delivery note 30112016 invoice date 03.01.2016"

The regex I made get all the dates:

```
[0-9]{1,2}[-.\/][0-9]{1,2}[-.\/][0-9]{2,4}
```

How to add the condition that it picks the date preceded "delivery date"?

Comment: Add it to the pattern and capture the date - `/delivery date\s*(\d{1,2}[-.\/]\d{1,2}[-.\/]\d{2,4})/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `delivery date` to the pattern and capture the date:

```
s[/delivery date\s*(\d{1,2}[-.\/]\d{1,2}[-.\/]\d{2,4})/, 1]
```

See the [online Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/vJ3Cdy)

The `1` argument tells Ruby to only fetch the contents *captured* within the first capturing group now.

Just in case you are interested in dates that have consistent separators, you may consider using

```
/delivery date\s*(\d{1,2}([-.\/])\d{1,2}\2\d{2,4})/
                         ^^^^^^^^       ^^
```

where the separator is captured into Group 2 and the value is re-used later with the backreference `\2`.

Comment: on rubular.com it gives no matches. Don't see the difference?

Comment: See [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/swuM2lcVNC). Everything works as expected. I forgot to add the trailing regex delimiter in the second example, fixed now. [Here](http://rubular.com/r/erSVHJNmRE) is the link to the second pattern demo.

Comment: how do i then add capturing only the date (w/out the term delivery date)? like you did with the ...,1]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. How many matches per string do you need? The `s[/regex/, n]` notation will help you get 1 subgroup. If you need more, you will need `.scan`.

Comment: only one - tubular gives both match result and match group. May be lack of understanding the difference between those. Match group is what is returned?

Comment: Rubular shows the whole matchdata object structure: match value and capture group values. When you use `s[/rx/, n]`, you tell Ruby to only return the value of the nth capture group. That is it.

Comment: ah, now understand match group! TX! when I use "date\s*(\d{1,2}([-.\/])\d{1,2}\2\d{2,4})/" it returns 2 match groups and the ,n is Ruby specific (which is not supported by Rubular - correct ?)

Comment: Rubular only shows the matchdata object. What you take from it inside Ruby code is entirely up to you.